# Vim global variable check throws error in lua (neovim plugin development)

Tags: lua, vim-plugin, neovim

I'm trying write a neovim plugin using lua, when checking if a variable exists, lua throws an error like: `Undefined variable: g:my_var`

Method 1:

```
local function open_bmax_term()
    if (vim.api.nvim_eval("g:my_var")) then
        print('has the last buff')
    else
        print('has no the last buff')
    end
end
```

Method 2:

```
local function open_bmax_term()
    if (vim.api.nvim_get_var("my_var")) then
        print('has the last buff')
    else
        print('has no the last buff')
    end
end
```

this is a similar function written in `viml` which does works: (this does not throw any error)

```
fun! OpenBmaxTerm()

    if exists("g:my_var")
        echo "has the last buff"
    
    else
        echo "has no the last buff"
    endif
endfun
```

any idea how to get this working in lua? I tried wrapping the condition inside a `pcall` which had an effect like making it always truthy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`vim.api.nvim_eval("g:my_var")` just evaluates a vimscript expression, so accessing a non-existent variable would error just like in vimscript. Have you tried `vim.api.nvim_eval('exists("g:my_var")')` instead?

---

Edit: Using `vim.g` as @andrewk suggested is probably the better solution as using the dedicated API is more elegant than evaluating strings of vim script.

Comment: hi thanks, this worked, it returned 0 or 1 depending on the status, i can use that in the condition

Answer (score 10):

You can use the global `g:` dictionary via `vim.g` to reference your variable:

```lua
if vim.g.my_var == nil then
    print("g:my_var does not exist")
else
    print("g:my_var was set to "..vim.g.my_var)
end
```

You can reference `:h lua-vim-variables` to see other global Vim dictionaries that are available as well!

Comment: This method is not correct: a global variable can take a value of false, then the checking condition is invalid.

Comment: Updated the condition to be an explicit nil check.